# getting txt from host and formating output for distribution

Tags: linux, awk, scripting

I fear that this is a very easy task, but I can find nothing related so here goes.

I have a text file that I am getting from several hosts. Based on the way the SSH script gets that data, is it basically the output of the commands I am executing, and thus, output, then output then output, example below.

```
hostname
1:card/function 
2:card/function 
3:card/function
4:card/function 
5:card/function 
6:card/function 
7:card/function 
8:card/function 
9:card/fucntion 
hostname 
1:card/function 
2:card/function 
3:card/function 
4:card/function 
5:card/function 
6:card/function 
7:card/function 
8:card/function 
9:card/function
```

this repeats a number of times.

I would like to format the output such that;

HOSTNAME  |           Slot1    |       Slot2    |       Slot3         |.......         Slot9 |

```
hostname 1:card/function 2:card/function 3:card/function .......9:card/function
hostname 1:card/function 2:card/function 3:card/function .......9:card/function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`

```
awk '{$1=$1;printf (/hostname/&&NR>1?RS:"")"%s ",$0} END {print ""}'
hostname 1:card/function 2:card/function 3:card/function 4:card/function 5:card/function 6:card/function 7:card/function 8:card/function 9:card/fucntion
hostname 1:card/function 2:card/function 3:card/function 4:card/function 5:card/function 6:card/function 7:card/function 8:card/function 9:card/fucntion
```

Your data seems to have space after it in some line. The `$1=$1` fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{printf "%s%s" , (NR>1&&(!/^[0-9]/)?"\n":""),$0} END{print ""}' file
```

this allows dynamic (real) hostname string.

(valid hostname doesn't allow to start with number, if your real data don't have the beginning `number:` like `1:....`,  you can check `/(slash)` , valid hostname doesn't allow to have `slash` either.